# Set Android BroadcastReceiver on React Native

Tags: android, service, react-native, android-broadcastreceiver, notification-listener

I am building an application on React Native and I would like to use the Android Service NotificationListenerService. In order to capture data from the service, I need a Broadcast Receiver. How can I set the BroadcastReceiver up at the React Native Environment?

Comment: try: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way I did it is to `emit` event using `getJSModule`

MyListener.java

```
public class MyListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        if (sbn.getNotification().tickerText == null) {
            return;
        }

        WritableNativeMap params = new WritableNativeMap();
        params.putString("tickerText", sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString());
        params.putString("packageName", sbn.getPackageName());

        MyModule.sendEvent("notificationReceived", params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {}
}
```

MyModule.java

```
public class MyModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener {
    private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    public MyModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
        reactContext.addActivityEventListener(this);
    }

    public static void sendEvent(String event, WritableNativeMap params) {
        reactContext
            .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
            .emit(event, params);
    }
    .......
}
```

Check [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript) for more details about sending events.

Comment: Did it work? It seems I can't instantiate an WritableMap object.

Comment: It's actually `WritableNativeMap`. Updated my answer.

Comment: i'm pretty new to react native so I don't fully understand eventListeners. Apparently, on the module, the compiler can't find `this.reactContext`. Is this part correct?

Comment: Yes it's correct. Check out my module for a complete example https://github.com/nerdyfactory/things-notification

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helped a lot!!! You're the best! BTW, very elegant solution.

Comment: This is not a great idea because holding context in a static variable can cause memory leaks. See https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html